# UIscrollview populated with InterfaceBuilder with autolayout set, doesn't scroll after screen rotation

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I'm relatively new to iOS world, so i have this problem that i think is quite common: i want to populate a scrollview using InterfaceBuilder (not programmatically) keeping autolayout active.
I read Apple's doc [mixed approach](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013309-CH1-MIXED_APPROACH).
So i create a child view for the scrollview and add items to childview and set `[scrollView setContentSize:CGMakeSize(contentWidth,contentHeight)];`
but when i rotate the device, scrollview doesn't scroll anymore, even if i go back to PORTRAIT orientation.

How can i make it work? Please remember that i don't want to define all the children views programmatically and i don't want to setup constraints programmatically (otherwise IB becomes completely useless and all UI development time becomes too long)

Comment: Instead of adding it to child view you can embed it in UIScrollView.

Comment: It is (child view which is parent of all other views) already embedded into the scrollview as stated in Apple's doc

Comment: No, try to embed all other views into scrollview instead of child view.